# How much memory is used by "missing optional"/"empty repeated" fields in ProtoBuf?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm trying to design my first file format in ProtoBuf, and I'm not sure what is the best choice in some cases, because the memory/stream layout is not totally clear to me.

So I have in fact several questions, but all closely related:

1) What does an optional field cost, when it is omitted?

I think it should only cost one *bit*, since a bit-field can be used to flag present/absent fields, but I don't know for sure. They might instead use a whole byte per optional field.

2) What does a repeated field cost when it is empty? Is it also one bit, like the optional field, or is it "field header" + one (varint) byte to say it is size 0?

3) Since "bytes" implicitly has a size, is there actually a size difference between a missing optional bytes field, and an empty required bytes field?

[EDIT] By "memory" I meant space used on the file-system or network bandwidth; I did not mean RAM, since this would be programming-language-dependent.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1: nothing whatsoever - it is omitted completely on the wire

2: nothing whatsoever - only actual contents are included; an empty list is essentially omitted (possible exception: empty "packed" arrays; although even that could legitimately be omitted)

3: omitted costs nothing; present and zero-length costs **at least** 2 bytes - one field header (length depends on field number; low field numbers < 16 take 1 byte), and one length of zero (one byte)

Additional note: protobuf never uses sub-byte packing, so any field always uses an entire number of bytes.

(context: I've written a protobuf implementation from first principles, so the [encoding details](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/encoding.html) are fairly familiar to me)

Comment: I've read the documentation you linked to and didn't see anything that explicitly said that omitted `optional` fields are not omitted on the wire. The documenation states that `the encoded message may or may not have a key-value pair with that tag number,` which doesn't sound like a guarantee. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @Elpezmuerto https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#optional - the key point is the "zero or more"; the entire point of "omitted" is that it is the zero case. And it is precisely this that allows forward compatibility of messages. Yes, the writer *could* emit the bytes for the default value, but then it wouldn't be "omitted" - it would definitely have a value, and the receiver would not be able to detect that it was the omitted value

Comment: I think it is only field numbers 1 to 15 take one byte after that 2

Comment: @osundblad you're right, brain-fart there